# Can we a static ( A Utility class) method for a webservice

Tags: web-services

Inside a Webservice method , i have created a helper class whose responsibility is to take the XML String passed as  a Method arguement to it and then construct 
Array List obect from that .

My question is can i have this method as static ?? 
This utility methos will be called from a Webservice ?? Is this okay ??

```
public class UtilStaxParser {
    public static List parseData(String XMLdocument) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can... you would have found that if you had simply tried it :)
The webservice method can call a static method, but the webservice method cannot be static.